# How to set a mixer enum value in pyalsaaudio?

Tags: python, python-2.7, alsa

I'm using the python wrapper for the ALSA API called pyalsaaudio.

The part that I most care, is the Mixer API. 
With that I can get all the posible values of a Mixer like this:

```
Mixer.getenum()
```

For Example:

```
>>> import alsaaudio
>>> m = alsaaudio.Mixer('Mono Output Select')
>>> m.getenum()
('Mix', ['Mix', 'Mic'])
```

As you can see, the method getenum() returns a tuple, with all the possible values in case is not a volume control.
However, I don't know how to set any of those enum values!
Apparently, there is not a setnum() method. Documentation doesn't describe anything about how to set that kind of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyalsaaudio` does not have any mechanism to set enum controls.

Comment: Unfortunetly, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
m.setenum(1)
```

It works with the `0.8.4` version of `pyalsaaudio` (installed with `pip`).

The value of the enum is the position into the array, in your case `Mic`.

Comment: Mmmmm.... I asked this question 3 years ago, I'm not sure how many improvements have made pyalsaaudio from that time.